# How to provide binary field with Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is it possible to provide a backend endpoint where the response is a json containing some field values and a data blob?

I have the following model and serializer:

```
class NiceModel(db_models.Model):
    index = db_models.IntegerField()
    binary_data = db_models.BinaryField()

class NiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.NiceModel
        fields = (
            "index",
            "binary_data",
        )
```

this serializer produces a json like the following:

```
   {
        "index": 1,
        "binary_data": "veryveryveryveryveryverylongtext"
   }
```

Is this very long text a string representation of the binary data handled by DRE? If so, how can I read this data with javascript? Am I doing it the wrong way? should I create an endpoint only for the blob data and forget about the json format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, BinaryField is being represented in JSON by default. You should consider of writing own field if you need one. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields